# Squarespace code injection help - flat-iron template hover effects

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, squarespace

Within the index gallery, the Flat-iron template allows for an opacity change when you hover, but I'm wondering if I can reverse it i.e. have the images maintain a low opacity until you hover over for them to reveal the true image. **(i.e. How do I make the thumbnails appear as having a dark overlay until you hover over to reveal the true image)**

I want to make sure that when I insert the code, it doesn't cancel out the other hover over effects in place in the template - such as the image zoom, text overlay, and the fade-in fade-out.
__
I'm also wondering for an Option 2 (if this is an easier solution?), I'm wondering if its possible to have the images appear black and white until you hover revealing the colors).

Sorry, I know that's kind of 2 questions smushed into one post. Nonetheless, thank you for your help!! Seriously appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to do either one, although I can't speak for what happens with the other effects in the template. The best way to figure that out is to inspect the CSS for whatever element you're working with and see what's there.

The CSS `filter` property allows you to change the grayscale level of an image. So, you could do this:

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /*Chrome*/
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /*Chrome*/
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

This (of course) doesn't work on various Microsoft browsers, including Edge 12.

With opacity, you do much the same thing:

```
img {
    opacity: .8;
}

img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Now, you have to be a bit careful if you have a number of theme-generated effects, especially when using opacity. For example, if you have a text overlay on your image (as you probably do), then reducing the opacity of the image can also reduce the opacity of the text overlay, depending on how it's constructed in HTML. (If, for example, you set a div's opacity, every element in its container will inherit the setting.) If you have trouble with opacity, an alternative is to set the opacity in `filter`, much as you would set grayscale.

For more information on the `filter` property (which will let you do all kinds of tricks with images), have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp). In particular, have a look at brightness. That's what I would think of using first, rather than opacity or grayscale: set the brightness to, say, .9, and change it to full on hover.

You also have to be careful if you have things like fade-in effects, which can make your hover effects look pretty strange. For example, if there's some sort of fade-in when you hover over one of your images, changing the grayscale abruptly is going to look wrong. You'll need to make the change fade in at the same speed that your other fade-in effect is happening.

To do this, have a look at the CSS `transition` property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp).